# Чемпион спринтер(ов)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, склонение, орфоэпия

Как правильно: "чемпион спринтер" или "чемпион спринтеров"?

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: Чемпион-спринтер. Иначе получится, что у спринтеров есть чемпион. Суть в том, что спринтер является чемпионом.

Дополнение

Пишутся через дефис:сочетания с однословными приложениями, следующими за определяемым словом, напр.: ***город-герой, ковёр-самолёт, лён-долгунец, мать-героиня,***

См.: Полный академический справочник.

Answer (score 0):

РАЗНЫЕ ИСТОРИИ ПРО ЧЕМПИОНОВ И СПРИНТЕРОВ (В РАЗЛИЧНЫХ СОЧЕТАНИЯХ)

Гепард держит рекорд скорости среди наземных животных - на коротких дистанциях он развивает до 110 км/ч, а расстояние в 500 м преодолевает со средней скоростью 100 км/ч. Для сравнения, ЧЕМПИОНЫ-СПРИНТЕРЫ пробегают 100 м за 10 с, то есть со средней скоростью меньше 40 км/ч.

Антропологи изучали феномен бегунов с Ямайки, среди которых очень много успешных спринтеров, в том числе и Усейн Болт, сообщает "Газета.ru". Ученые сделали вывод, что СПРИНТЕРЫ-ЧЕМПИОНЫ обладают идеально симметричными коленями. Спринтер Усейн Болт также входит в их число.

Шестикратный олимпийский ЧЕМПИОН СПРИНТЕР Усэйн Болт решил помочь трехкратной чемпионке...

Птеринохилус Муринус - ЧЕМПИОН СРЕДИ СПРИНТЕРОВ, это уж точно.
До сих пор помню свой ночной кошмар - носится за мной муринус размером с добермана. А я от него отпрыгивать пытаюсь. Носится со скоростью формулы-1. По ночам регулярно наблюдал телепортацию этого паука. Как свет включается - замирает. Чуть где что шелохнётся - с бешеной скоростью долбя лапами по стеклу начинала носиться по терру в поисках гнезда.

ВЫВОД

Старайтесь  не ограничивать свою авторскую мысль орфографическими запретами.

Comment: Вера, не совсем понятно, к чему Вы приводите последний пример. К нашему случаю он не относится.  Что касается правил: вы призываете не соблюдать их?

Comment: Есть определенные правила, на основании которых нужен дефис.

Comment: Серж, последний пример к тому, что  у спринтеров, вопреки Вашему утверждению, может быть чемпион, но только он называется "чемпион среди спринтеров". А все мое остальное рассуждение - это призыв к пониманию того, что каждая форма несет особенное содержание: спринтер-чемпион, чемпион-  спринтер и т.д. - всё это должно соответствовать ситуации. А про конкретную ситуацию в вопросе ничего не сказано, вот и сложно ответить. А правило - это же святое, как их не соблюдать!

Comment: Чемпион спринтеров и чемпион среди среди спринтеров не совсем одно и тоже. Пр первом можно подумать спринтеры обладают чемпионом, или чемпион над спринтерами. Такое словосочетание некорректно. И еще: в чем разница между чемпион спринтер и чемпион-спринтер?

Comment: Чемпион спринтеров - неправильно, в словаре указывается обязательное предложное управление (предлоги ПО, СРЕДИ). Чемпион-спринтер, здесь главное слово "чемпион", спринтер-чемпион, здесь главное слово спринтер. Раздельное написание: неоднородные приложения перед именем собственным.

Comment: Вера, профессор по химии. Здесь тоже связь управление. но: профессор-химик.

Answer (score 0):

Для ответа контекст нужен (более длинная фраза).

Возможно "чемпион-спринтер" или "чемпион спринтеров" - в зависимости от смысла.
И то и другое вызывает вопросы по стилистике.
Ибо первое означает скорее, что некто стал чемпионом очень быстро, в спринтерском темпе. А второе невольно выводит на существующие, но крайне малоупотребительные значения слова "чемпион" не связанные с соревнованиями (ну вроде выборная такая должность).

Нейтральным я бы счел ***"спринтер-чемпион"*** - т.е. чемпион в соревнованиях по спринту. Тут никаких двусмысленностей, да и и порядок составляющих естественный: приложение в конце. Ведь он прежде всего ***спринтер***, а что еще и ***чемпион*** - так это "лучший спринтер", "спринтер-победитель"...

Comment: behemothus, а какой смысл вы вкладываете в словосочетание **Чемпион спринтеров**?

Comment: "behemothus, а какой смысл вы вкладываете в словосочетание Чемпион спринтеров? " - Я - никакого. Изначально неудачная конструкция. здесь, думаю, имеется в виду именно спринтер-чемпион.  А получается "адвокат, защитник, представитель..." . Да мало ли что...

Comment: Я написал в  ответе.

Comment: "Я написал в ответе". - Я тоже. Мне не очень нравится ваш ответ.  Чемпион-спринтер - плохо. А "чемпион спринтеров" - что-то очень далекое от чемпионства - в спортивном его смысле. В самом простом случае - просто "лучший". А вообще без контекста обсуждать бессмысленно.

Comment: А что вам не нравится? Здесь инверсия. А удачна такая инверсия или нет - вопрос стилистики. Автора интересовало как правильно написать. Я и ответил.  А чемпион спринтеров вообще бессмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Контекст:

Эта лошадь - чемпион спринтеров в России в 2009 году.

То есть, "у спринтеров есть чемпион". Именно так, как написано у behemothus.
Суть в том, что эта лошадь чемпион (среди/в числе всех) спринтеров 2009 года.